# How can I check for the existence of a global variable in React (when compiling with ESLint)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I have a global object that is present only sometimes. In my Create React App project I want to use a conditional to set different value depending on if this global object exists. However, ESLint is preventing me from compiling as it does not like undefined variables.

I can check if a variable is undefined like:

```
if (typeof componentObj === "undefined") {
  message = "Default message";
}
```

ESLint is happy with this. But I cannot then add an `else` to that, e.g.:

```
if (typeof componentObj === "undefined") {
  message = "Default message";
}
else {
  message = componentObj.message;
}
```

ESLint will error out with the undefined `componentObj.message;` in the else statement.

How can I get around this?

Comment: If you're just asking how to tell ESLint `componentObj` could exist, see https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-globals. Also note you can write that as `message = componentObj?.message ?? "Default message"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I got get ESLint to ignore certain lines by adding the comment:

`// eslint-disable-line`.

So for the above I can do:

```
  if (typeof componentObj === "undefined") {
    greeting = 'Data not from component object';
  }
  else {
    greeting = componentObj.title;  // eslint-disable-line
  }
```

And it will compile.

Answer (score -1):

```js
if (typeof componentObj === "undefined") {
  message = "Default message";
}
else if("message" in componentObj) {
  message = componentObj.message;
}

// OR

if (typeof componentObj === "undefined") {
  message = "Default message";
}
else if(componentObj.hasOwnProperty("message")) {
  message = componentObj.message;
}
```